# Local Log Analyzer Tool

Tags: logging, splunk, log-analysis

At work we have Splunk in Production. That is a powerful tool that generates timecharts, statistics, tables, groupings from logs in real time.
However sometimes I have to analyse logs that are not indexed in splunk, hence I spend a lot of time using grep, awk, sed and excel (to plot graphs).

Do you know any tool that can be easily installed on my local machine and offers features to analyze logs like Splunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Splunk? :P

Get yourself a Dev license and you'll be able to ingest several gigs of data daily. https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/

Or just use the free Splunk license, which gives you pretty much all the search capabilities, but a few limits around authentication and alerting. Shouldn't be a problem for a local instance however. Only 500mb a day, but that limit can breached irregularly.

https://www.splunk.com/en_us/software/features-comparison-chart.html

Comment: I don't know hot easy it's to install Splunk, but I accept your answer.
The only problem is that I'm trying to create a free account and I receive this:

Due to US export compliance requirements, Splunk has temporarily suspended your access. Please call Splunk Customer Support at 1-(855) XXX-XXXX for assistance. You may be asked to provide additional information, including your full name, complete mailing address, email and the Splunk.com username you created during your registration.
So that is not so easy. /o\